# Swift - Get last 7 days starting from today in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, days

How to get previous 7 days of the month I know how to get if today is 18, but what if today id 3rd November? How to get the last 4 days from the previous month(October) in Int?

Comment: What do you mean by `Int`? Unix timestamp or sth?

Comment: [27,28,29,30,1,2,3] or [28,29,30,31,1,2,3] it depends from the month

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
// start with today
var date = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

var days = [Int]()

for i in 1 ... 7 {
    // get day component:
    let day = cal.component(.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
    days.append(day)

    // move back in time by one day:
    date = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.DayCalendarUnit, value: -1, toDate: date, options: nil)!
}

println(days)
```

**Update for Swift 2.2 (Xcode 7.3.1):**

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
var date = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
var days = [Int]()
for i in 1 ... 7 {
    let day = cal.component(.Day, fromDate: date)
    days.append(day)
    date = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: date, options: [])!
}
print(days)
```

Update for **Swift 3 (Xcode 8 beta 2):**

```
let cal = Calendar.current
var date = cal.startOfDay(for: Date())
var days = [Int]()
for i in 1 ... 7 {
    let day = cal.component(.day, from: date)
    days.append(day)
    date = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date)!
}
print(days)
```

Comment: Do we need `.startOfDayForDate()`?, for leap second?

Comment: @rintaro: I prefer a well-defined time component when working with dates. But it is not really need here. Leap seconds are not considered in Unix time, so that plays no role.

Comment: @MartinR will appreciate if u answer my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238994/get-previous-current-and-next-weeks-excluding-saturday-and-sunday

Comment: @MartinR: What is the way to achieve the days like `[Dec 26, Dec 27]` this format?

Comment: @iPeter: Use a DateFormatter to convert the dates to strings. You'll find examples in the other answers below, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375155/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you so much. Appreciate it.

Comment: @MartinR: Got it! You're AWESOME sir! :D

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26996630/3411787) answer,

Get list of previous **N** days as an array of strings.

```
extension Date {
    static func getDates(forLastNDays nDays: Int) -> [String] {
        let cal = NSCalendar.current
        // start with today
        var date = cal.startOfDay(for: Date())

        var arrDates = [String]()

        for _ in 1 ... nDays {
            // move back in time by one day:
            date = cal.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.day, value: -1, to: date)!

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            arrDates.append(dateString)
        }
        print(arrDates)
        return arrDates
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let last7Days = Date.getDates(forLastNDays: 7)
debugPrint(last7Days)

//Today(2017-11-19) it prints: ["2017-11-18", "2017-11-17", "2017-11-16", "2017-11-15", "2017-11-14", "2017-11-13", "2017-11-12"]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create an extension using Calendar to help you with your calendrical calculations:

**Swift 3 or later**

```
extension Date {
    var day: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self)
    }
    func adding(days: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: self)!
    }
    var last7days: [Int] {
        return (1...7).map { 
            adding(days: -$0).day
        }
    }
    func near(days: Int) -> [Int] {
        return days == 0 ? [day] : (1...abs(days)).map {
            adding(days: $0 * (days < 0 ? -1 : 1) ).day
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let last7Days  = Date().last7days   // [29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23]
let last7Days2 = Date().near(days: -7) // [29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23]
let next7Days  = Date().near(days: 7) // [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2]
```

---

Same strategy as @rintaro answer, as short as possible ;) (added support to negative values and made it as a Date extension to be able to use any date as input)

```
extension Date {
    func closest(days: Int) -> [Int] {
        return days == 0 ? [] : (1...abs(days)).map { delta -> Int in Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: delta * (days >= 0 ? 1 : -1), to: self)!) }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let next7Days2 = Date().closest(days: 7) // [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2]
let last7Days3 = Date().closest(days: -7) // [25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19]
let next2Days = Date().closest(days: 2) // [27, 28]
let last2Days = Date().closest(days: -2) // [25, 24]
```

Answer (score 5):

Same strategy as @MartinR answer, as short as possible:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let date = NSDate()

var result = map(-6...0) { delta -> Int in
    cal.component(.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: cal.dateByAddingUnit(.DayCalendarUnit, value: delta, toDate: date, options: nil)!)
}
```

Comment: Nice. I like the way you use map()

Answer (score 1):

It's might not be the fastest code. But you get the idea :)

```
import Foundation

let lastSevenDay: [Int] = {
    var days = [Int]()
    let secondsInADay: NSTimeInterval = 24 * 60 * 60
    let now = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
    for i in 1...7 {
        let theDate = now.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-secondsInADay * NSTimeInterval(7 - i))
        let dateComponent = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: theDate)
        let dayOfMonth = dateComponent.day
        days.append(dayOfMonth)
    }
    return days
}()
```

Comment: Not every day has 86400 seconds (think of the transition to and from Daylight Saving Time). Using 60*60*24 as the duration for a day is wrong.

Comment: Yep. Thank you for pointing that out. We dont have DST here so I didnt think about it. I've voted for your solution since it's correct and more concise :)

Answer (score 1):

I modified the rintaro answer a bit to get past dates in a NSArray of NSDictionaries to get all values including past days, months and years. You only need to call this snippet like this

```
println(getPastDates(2))
```

to get a full list with past dates like that

(
        {
        day = 30;
        month = 11;
        year = 2014;
    },
        {
        day = 29;
        month = 11;
        year = 2014;
    }
)

```
func getPastDates(days: Int) -> NSArray {

    var dates = NSMutableArray()

    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    var today = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

    for i in 1 ... days {

        let day = cal.component(.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: today)
        let month = cal.component(.MonthCalendarUnit, fromDate: today)
        let year = cal.component(.YearCalendarUnit, fromDate: today)

        var date = NSMutableDictionary()

        date.setValue(day, forKey: "day")
        date.setValue(month, forKey: "month")
        date.setValue(year, forKey: "year")

        dates.addObject(date)

        // move back in time by one day:
        today = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.DayCalendarUnit, value: -1, toDate: today, options: nil)!
    }

    return dates

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I update

Alejandro Luengo's code. It works Swift4

```
func getPastDates(days: Int) -> NSMutableArray {

        let dates = NSMutableArray()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        var today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())

        for _ in 1 ... days {

            let day = calendar.component(.day, from: today)
            let month = calendar.component(.month, from: today)
            let year = calendar.component(.year, from: today)

            let date = NSMutableDictionary()

            date.setValue(day, forKey: "day")
            date.setValue(month, forKey: "month")
            date.setValue(year, forKey: "year")

            dates.add(date)
            today = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: today)!
        }

        return dates

    }
```

Comment: I appreciate you. :D

Answer (score 1):

**Swift4**

Same strategy as @MartinR, @rintaro answer, as short as possible:

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = Date()

    let result: [Int] = (-6...0).map { delta -> Int in
        calendar.component(.day, from: calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: delta, to: date)!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `NSCalendar` to get the last 7 days. Here's a code snippet to demonstrate it in action for 3rd November:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("03/11/14")!
println("date = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))")

let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
var previous7days: Array<Int> = []
for i in 0...6 {
    let prevDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: -i, toDate: date, options:  nil)
    previous7days.insert(calendar.component(.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: prevDate!), atIndex: 0)
}
println("last 7 days: \(previous7days)")
```

Comment: Not every day has 86400 seconds (think of the transition to and from Daylight Saving Time). Using 60*60*24 as the duration for a day is wrong.

Comment: Yep, that's why your answer is the better one ;)