# Get Previous, Current and Next Weeks Excluding Saturday and Sunday

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I wants to display dates/days from **Monday** to **Friday** excluding **Saturday/Sunday** as mentioned in the image below.

[image]

**My Scenario:**

1. When screen loads the current week should display.
2. On previous button click (**DisplayedWeek - 1**)
3. On Next button click     (**DisplayedWeek + 1**).

**My Work**,

After some research this is what i have tried.

```
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let currentDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())

        /* value =  0 for current,
           value =  1 for next,
           value = -1 for previous week.

        */
        let nextWeek:Date =  calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfMonth, value: 1, to: currentDate)! as Date

        let dayOfWeek = calendar.component(.weekday, from: nextWeek)
        let weekdays = calendar.range(of: .weekday, in: .weekOfYear, for: nextWeek)!

        let days = (weekdays.lowerBound ..< weekdays.upperBound).flatMap {

            calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0 - dayOfWeek, to: nextWeek)

        }.filter { !calendar.isDateInWeekend($0) }

        // Week Days from monday to friday
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        for date in days {
            print(formatter.string(from: date))
        }
```

In my case if the day is **Saturday** or **Sunday** it should display next week but it is displaying the same week.

Comment: What "timezone related issues" do you have? Please show a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem clearly.

Comment: @MartinR some details added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the [current week monday's date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33398047/2303865), and just add n days to it:

**Swift 4.1 • Xcode 9.3 or later**

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}
extension Date {
    var cureentWeekMonday: Date {
        return Calendar.iso8601.date(from: Calendar.iso8601.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))!
    }
    var currentWeekdays: [Date] {
        return (0...4).compactMap{ Calendar.iso8601.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: $0), to: cureentWeekMonday) } // for Swift versions earlier than 4.1 use flatMap instead
    }
}
```

---

```
let currentWeekdays = Date().currentWeekdays
print(currentWeekdays)  // ["Jul 17, 2017, 12:00 AM", "Jul 18, 2017, 12:00 AM", "Jul 19, 2017, 12:00 AM", "Jul 20, 2017, 12:00 AM", "Jul 21, 2017, 12:00 AM"]
```

Comment: how to display previous/next weeks?

Comment: When the current day is Saturday or Sunday it display the same week whereas i want to display the next week.

Comment: Just add or subtract one week to the current week days array elements

Comment: You should add all that extra info to the question. just add a conditional if weekday > friday you get the next week.

Comment: Official time in my place is 12:06A.M. your function is also returning Sunday i.e. `2017-07-16`,  complete output: `[2017-07-16 19:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-17 19:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-18 19:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-19 19:00:00 +0000, 2017-07-20 19:00:00 +0000]`

Comment: don't mess with timezone. Use it as it is. To display your date at local time use DateFormatter

Comment: ok  Got it Thanks sir. using `let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        for date in currentWeekdays {
            print(formatter.string(from: date))
        }` resolved my problem