# Is the Swift Calendar stuct thread safe?

Tags: swift

I am trying to determine if the swift Calendar struct is thread safe.  I found that the NSCalendar class is "[generally considered to be thread safe](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html)".  But I can not find specific information for the Calendar struct.

My goal is to extend the Date struct with a Calendar for use with extension methods such as yesterday, tomorrow, etc.  I don't want to create a new Calendar instance with each call.

Comment: `extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601 = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
}`

Comment: and just use `Calendar.iso8601.whatever` https://stackoverflow.com/a/45242626/2303865

Comment: To Leo's point, that works, but depending upon what sorts of functions you are using, it might be more prudent to use `Calendar.current`. ISO 8601 is fine for dates in web services or databases, but for anything you're showing to the end user, `Calendar.current` would be better.

Comment: Thanks, currently, for my app, I'm only supporting Gregorian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Calendar` is meant to be a drop-in replacement for `NSCalendar`, and in fact is just a wrapper around `NSCalendar` on Apple platforms, so if `NSCalendar` is thread-safe, I'd expect that `Calendar` is as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at [Calendar's source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4654a230fb67fc8ba34348c1f5f3758292223260/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Calendar.swift), you won't see any code to make it thread safe. So I think it's not, and different threads will see different versions of the `Calendar`'s object fields.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not thread-safe (at least when running on Linux). Not sure if Darwin implementation is different. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11323

If anybody is curious the implementation is here: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/CoreFoundation/Locale.subproj/CFCalendar.c

There are lots of places where "calendar->_cal" (which is shared between concurrent invocations) is modified and used as a temporary storage.